# jqGrid adjust column size depending on text length

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the column of a grid depending on its contents. 
This is only the case for specific columns.
What I've done so far is adjust the colModel by looping through the rows and comparing the length of the content.

If the content exceeds the previous known length, it adjusts the colModel again. 
It looks something like this.

```
        // Get rowId's and get find the longest content
        $.each(grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), function(row, rowid) {
            // Loop through the specified columns
            $.each(abo_fields, function(colid, column) {
                var abo = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, column);
                var new_width = abo.length * 8;
                var current = grid.jqGrid('getColProp', column);
                if(current['width'] < new_width) {
                    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', column, {width:new_width});
                }                    
            });
        });
```

The colModel is adjusted when I request the getColProp. 
When I use the grid.trigger('reloadGrid'); the column seem to stay the same as specified in the original colModel.
I also tried adjusting the CSS through jquery, but that was no success either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more digging in the colModel options and found the following:

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)

> Below are options which can not be changed dynamically when the grid is constructed (If changed they do not have effect or will cause the grid errors). For some of these options there are methods available to change the value.

```
name
width
resizable
label (method avail.)
```

The jqGrid wiki says the following aswell if and when you really need this. Just remember that when this is done, any logic built in the grid is gone.

> Reloads the grid with the current settings. This means that a new request is send to the server if datatype is xml or json. This method should be applied to an already-constructed grid. Pay attention that this method does not change HEADER information, that means that any changes to colModel would not be affected. You should use gridUnload to reload new configuration with different colModel. IT'S WORK ONLY IF loadonce: false !!!

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

Hop this helps someone else too :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I implement variable column widths based off the text contents - add this to the gridComplete event:

```
$('#parent').append('<span id="widthTest" />');

                gridName = this.id;

                $('#gbox_' + gridName + ' .ui-jqgrid-htable,#' + gridName).css('width', 'inherit');
                $('#' + gridName).parent().css('width', 'inherit');

                var columnNames = $("#" + gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                var thisWidth;

                // Loop through Cols
                for (var itm = 0, itmCount = columnNames.length; itm < itmCount; itm++) {

                    var curObj = $('[aria-describedby=' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ']');

                    var thisCell = $('#' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name + ' div');
                    $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.text()).css({
                            'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
                            'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
                            'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
                        });
                    var maxWidth = Width = $('#widthTest').width() + 24;                    
                    //var maxWidth = 0;                      

                    // Loop through Rows
                    for (var itm2 = 0, itm2Count = curObj.length; itm2 < itm2Count; itm2++) {
                        var thisCell = $(curObj[itm2]);

                        $('#widthTest').html(thisCell.html()).css({
                            'font-family': thisCell.css('font-family'),
                            'font-size': thisCell.css('font-size'),
                            'font-weight': thisCell.css('font-weight')
                        });

                        thisWidth = $('#widthTest').width();
                        if (thisWidth > maxWidth) maxWidth = thisWidth;                        
                    }                    

                    $('#' + gridName + ' .jqgfirstrow td:eq(' + itm + '), #' + gridName + '_' + columnNames[itm].name).width(maxWidth).css('min-width', maxWidth);

                }

                $('#widthTest').remove();
```

A working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ba5yK/17/

I hope someone finds this useful.

Regards,

Paul